# Prevent selecting cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, selection

I have little problem with DataGridView.
1. Drop DataGridView control on form and set property Visible to **False**
2. Add few rows and change visible to **True** like code above.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "a" });
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "b" });
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3", "c" });
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "4", "d" });

   dataGridView1.Visible = true;
               //^ this trigger selection

}

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("selected");
}
```

After setting Visible to True, first cell is automatically selected and trigger SelectionChanged event.
How to prevent that?

**EDIT. SOLUTION:**

- Detach event handler:
- Set visible
- Clear selection
- Add handler

---

```
dataGridView1.SelectionChanged -= dataGridView1_SelectionChanged;
dataGridView1.Visible = true;
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += dataGridView1_SelectionChanged;
```

Comment: I thinks your problem is that `dataGridView1_SelectionChanged` is being fired because of this line of code: `dataGridView1.Visible = true;`. Setting the grid's visibility will trigger the event. Why do you want to set the grid to false in the beginning?

Comment: I want to show grid in specific situation. At the beginning grid must be hidden.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution will prevent the event from firing, but I think the first cell will still be selected when the grid is shown. A simple call to ClearSelection() on the DataGridView should fix that.

Regards, Drew

Answer (score 1):

Set DataGridView's TabStop to false

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wiring and rewiring every time you alter the visible property, can you just not return from the method, if the visibility is false. That is:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!dataGridView1.Visible) return;
    Console.WriteLine("selected");
}
```

Comment: I only want disable selection for first time, when Visible going from False to True. After that user can select cell and trigger should work normal.

Comment: Agreed. I guess, that is exactly what would happen if you "return" when dataGridView1 isn't visible.